# Does Tirupati Balaji's idol have real hair?

Tags: vaishnavism, idols, tirupati

Namaste! I have read facts about Tirupati Balaji idol which is placed in sanctum sanctorum and among them there is one fact which raise my eyebrow: Idol has real hair and claimed to be real hair of lord himself, not a wig. They are smooth and shiny, never gets matted.

But, unfortunately there are no picture(s) of lord showcasing real hair.

> Is it true, that lord has real hair?

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion thank you! (Why your username is so intimidating?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Tirupati Venkateshwara doesn't have real hair. These are only rumours spreading over the internet.

Former chief priest of Tirumala, Ramana Deekshitulu confirmed that there is no real hair. Lord Venkateshwara has hair but which are a part of stone idol.

Below is his interview given in which he has busted a few rumours.

https://youtu.be/h-FkkDtiCI4

> Recently there are some rumours spreading on Whatsapp, YouTube. First of all. Lord having hair at the back. Having hair, it's smooth to touch, Lord's body is so tender to touch, he also grows nails. All these are characteristics of a materialistic human body. Lord is not materialistic. Alluding all these to Lord is an ignorance.

(Rough translation of Ramana Deekshitulu's words into English).

Comment: I wish someone who understands Telugu language should add subscripts to this video. Everyone will get benefit.